# How do I set an array of objects to state in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, javascript-objects

So I am doing an SQL query in my node/express backend and sending the result to my React front end through JSON. I am console.log to see what info I am sending and that seems to be in order. However, I can't seem to figure out how to set this array of objects to my state. I am getting this error:

"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Title}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Here is the component I am working with:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class ShoppingCart extends Component {
    state = {
       cartItems: ['Title 1']
    };


      displayCart = () => {

          console.log('call it')
          console.log('hello from displaycart');
          fetch('http://localhost:5000/fillCart')
          .then((res) => res.json())

          .then((json) => {
              this.setState(state => {
                  const cartItems = state.cartItems.concat(json.Title);
                  return {
                      cartItems
                  };
              });
          })
      }

      componentDidMount() {
          this.displayCart();
      }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="ShoppingCart">

                <h3>This is your shopping cart</h3>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.cartItems.map(item => (
                        <li key={item}>{item}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ShoppingCart
```

My goal is to set the json.Title (right now holding multiple titles) into the cartItems State array I have in my state, then display each title through render() in a list. However, I am stuck as to how to accomplish this.

Also, here is what the json data looks like that I send from the Node/express backend:

```
[
  RowDataPacket { Title: 'The Tragedy of The Korosko' },
  RowDataPacket { Title: 'Two in the Far North' }
]
```

To clarify, at this point my problem is not displaying the information, but rather setting it to the state in the first place.
 Any suggestions sure would be appreciated! I've been stuck on this for several days. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Could you show the structure of the JSON response please?

Comment: Show me the json data .

Comment: This is what the json looks like that I am sending to React:                                          
  [                                                                                                          
  RowDataPacket { Title: 'The Tragedy of The Korosko' },
  RowDataPacket { Title: 'Two in the Far North' }
]

Comment: Add it to the original question please, not in a comment. Really hard to read.

Comment: I just added the json data to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract all titles from the json response.

This is what the response format looks like:

```
{
  Title: [{Title: ''}, {Title: ''}]
}
```

Your top level `json.Title` is an array with objects.
So the `.Title` property does not exist on `json.Title`, but on each of the objects inside of the array.

We can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to pull out what we need.

Your setState could look something like this:

```
this.setState(state => {
    // All titles in an array
    const titles = json.Title.map(row => row.Title)

    // Add to existing ones
    const cartItems = state.cartItems.concat(titles);

    return {
        cartItems
    };
});
```

Comment: Right now it is giving me the following error: json.map is not a function. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: In that case, `json` is not what you showed it to be in the question. What does the `console.log(".then: " + json);` output @LukeSharon?

Comment: @OskarHane It is saying this:  .then: [object Object]

Comment: What about `console.log(JSON.stringify(json))` instead @LukeSharon?

Comment: @3limin4t0r  I changed the one line to what you suggested. It resulted in an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: yeah, just noticed. Thanks @3limin4t0r :)

Comment: I made a slight modification to @Oskar Hane's answer and included it in the answers. Thanks for the assistance!!!

Comment: Thanks @LukeSharon. I've updated my answer with the new format and the code change. I suggest you update your original question with the correct response format for any users coming here in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Array Spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) with current state and the JSON in response. Code will be like bellow:

```
displayCart = () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:5000/fillCart')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    const newItemsArry = json.map(itm=> itm.Titles)
    this.setState({cartItems: [...this.state.cartItems, newItemsArry]}))
  }
}
```

Comment: So update on this answer. It took away the error I referred to in my original question. However, upon opening my React tools in the browser, the state of cartItems is set to the following: cartItems: ["Title 1", undefined]. So basically the json object is still not being set to state. Any solutions for this problem?

Comment: Looks like what you are calling `json` is actually an array. This is very confusing. Anyway, I've updated my answer, this should work now. And find the JSON specification [here](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

Answer (score -1):

Oskar Hane had an answer that was pretty close. Here is his answer with a slight modification:

```
.then((json) => {
              this.setState(state => {
                  const titles = json.Title.map(row => row.Title)
                  const cartItems = state.cartItems.concat(titles);
                  return {
                      cartItems
                  };
              });
          })
      }
```

The change is in json.Title.map. It is necessary to map through an array; however, json.map is not mapping through an array because json is not an array. json.Title is the array.